# Figure or text outside a block in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

When making a poster with tikzposter, is there a method by which one can put a figure outside of a block, or even just some text? For example, a university logo in the corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can: In `tikzposter` you are already in a big `tikzpicture`. Just place your nodes as usual. The center of the page is `(0,0)`.

One can also mention that the class defines a coordinate `bottomleft` in the lower left corner and `topright` in the upper right, so these can be used to place stuff relative to corners.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter} 
\begin{document}

\node [above right,font=\Huge] at (bottomleft) {LOWER LEFT};

\node [above left,font=\Huge,outer sep=2cm] at (bottomleft -| topright) {LOWER RIGHT};

\node [below right,font=\Huge] at (bottomleft |- topright) {UPPER LEFT};

\node [below left,font=\Huge] at (topright) {UPPER RIGHT};

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the manual on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter). In section 4.1 you find the command `\titlegraphic{}` to add graphics to the title. Section 4.3 gives you some hints on the `\note` command to add text in a more or less arbitrary way. Does this help?